# How to check if a function has been called before executing another function everytime

Tags: javascript

I have a onMouseDownEssence() and onMouseUpEssence() function for an HTML element, how to check if onMouseDownEssence() is called every time before calling onMouseUpEssence() to ensure I get the correct mouse down position?

Here is mousedown function:

```
var mouseDownIndex = -1;

function onMouseDownEssence(downIndex, e, className) {

    dragTarget = e.target;
    holdStarter = new Date().valueOf();

    mouseDownIndex = downIndex;
}
```

Here is mouseup function:

```
function onMouseUpEssence(upIndex, e, className) {

    var el = e.target;
    var holdActive = (new Date().valueOf() - holdStarter) > holdDelay;

    if (holdActive) {
        var thisUpTargetIndex = el.getAttribute("name");

        if (lastUpTargetIndex != null && thisUpTargetIndex != lastUpTargetIndex) {
            // console.log("double drag done");
            el.removeAttribute(dbl);
            lastUpTargetIndex = null;

            var selectedText = clickDragAutoExpand(mouseDownIndex, upIndex,
                    className);

        } else {
            // console.log("drag done");
            var selectedText = clickDragAutoExpand(mouseDownIndex, upIndex,
                    className);
        }

        holdActive = false;
    } else if (el.getAttribute(dbl) == null) {
        el.setAttribute(dbl, 1);
        setTimeout(
                function() {
                    if (el.getAttribute(dbl) == 1 && !dragTarget) {
                        if (e.button === 0) {
                            // console.log("single clicked ");
                            el.removeAttribute(dbl);

                            var selectedText = clickAutoExpand(upIndex,
                                    className);

                        }
                    } else {
                        if (el.getAttribute(dbl) != null)
                            lastUpTargetIndex = el.getAttribute("name");
                    }
                }, dblDelay);
    } else {
        // console.log("double clicked");
        el.removeAttribute(dbl);

        var selectedText = clickAutoExpand(upIndex, className);
    }

    dragTarget = null;

}
```

Comment: Please, include some of your code in order for us to help you.

Comment: Also explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would be to keep a track of whether `mouseDownEssence()` was called. And if not, call it before proceeding further. This approach would work somewhat as below. It would work differently for asynchronous functions but `mouseDownEssence()` seems to be a synchronous function.

```
let isMouseDownEssenceCalled = false;

function mouseDownEssence() {
  isMouseDownEssenceCalled = true;

  ...
}

function mouseUpEssence() {
  if (!isMouseDownEssenceCalled) {
    mouseDownEssence()
  }

  ...

  isMouseDownEssenceCalled = false;
}
```

Comment: How to check if a function has been called AFTER executing another function everytime? Thanks.

Comment: The same principle applies. Use variables to keep track of function execution. Of course, as mentioned previously, different approach should be used for an asynchronous function.